# Python decorator works with staticmethod. But fails with 2 static methods. Why?

Tags: python, static-methods, python-decorators

Here is my python code. I have a class `MyClass` with two static methods: `my_method1` and `my_method2`. Both methods are wrapped with a decorator called `exception_handler`.

```
from functools import wraps
import sys

def exception_handler(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            print "EXCEPTION!: %s" % e
            sys.exit(-1)
    return decorator


class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    @exception_handler
    def my_method1(a, b, c,):
        return "X"

    @staticmethod
    @exception_handler
    def my_method2(e, f, g,):
        print "Y"
        return MyClass.my_method1(a=e, b=f, c=g)

print "Trying my_method1"
print MyClass.my_method1(1, 2, 3)

print ""
print "Trying my_method2"
print MyClass.my_method2(1, 2, 3)
```

When I run this code, I get the following:

```
Trying my_method1
X

Trying my_method2
Y
EXCEPTION!: decorator() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Why does the decorator fail in the second instance and how can I get around it?

It seems like the decorator fails when decorated method is a static method being called by another static method. But why this would happen makes no sense to me.

Comment: Why is there a "self" in inner function? Static methods do not get self or cls as first argument

Comment: `except Exception, e:`: please use `except Exception as e:` if possible. This syntax has been [deprecated since Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110-exception-handling-changes).

Comment: ozy. This decorator was intended to be used on both static methods and non-static class methods. It was working for both.... until I tried calling a wrapped static method from within another wrapped static method.

Comment: Thanks Evert for pointing that out. I will make the change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `staticmethods` do not take self as an argument. I am not sure why it works on the first two calls and not the third. However, removing `self` from the decorator fixes it.

Here is the refactored code:

```
from functools import wraps
import sys


def exception_handler(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print "EXCEPTION!: {}".format(e)
            sys.exit(-1)

    return decorator


class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    @exception_handler
    def my_method1(a, b, c, ):
        return "X"

    @staticmethod
    @exception_handler
    def my_method2(e, f, g, ):
        print "Y"
        return MyClass.my_method1(a=e, b=f, c=g)


print "Trying my_method1"
print MyClass.my_method1(1, 2, 3)

print
print "Trying my_method2"
print MyClass.my_method2(1, 2, 3)
```

Doing so gives these results:

```
Trying my_method1
X

Trying my_method2
Y
X
```

Comment: So I want such a decorator for exception-handling on both static and non-static methods. Do I just need two different decorators?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you will need to call your static methods like this: `MyClass.my_method1(_, 1, 2, 3)` ...

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is failing without you noticing, can you try printing your `a, b, c` *args ? You will find out that `a` is `self` !!! So it fails silently by assigning the wrong arguments.

Then why it raises an exception the second call here: `MyClass.my_method1(a=e, b=f, c=g)` that's because your *args are empty now and self cannot replace any variable like before.